# varnish / docker-compose custom port and cache size

Tags: docker-compose, varnish

I'm trying to figure out how to pass custom port and cache size and vcl file in docker-compose.yml to varnish (I'm using the official varnish image https://hub.docker.com/_/varnish )

I Tried using environment variables by adding the following lines into my docker-compose.yml but it seems that they are not taken into consideration

```
    environment:
      - VARNISH_CONFIG="/etc/varnish/custom.vcl"
      - CACHE_SIZE=512m
      - VARNISH_PORT=8080
```

Any clue on how to pass these params to a varnish container ?

Answer (score 1):

In case some one needs to achieve the same config, I ended up by creating a new image based on the official one and adding these params to the CMD instruction :

```
EXPOSE **8080**
CMD ["varnishd", "-F", "-f", "**/etc/varnish/custom.vcl**", "-s", "**malloc,2G**"]
```

Comment: you'll also want to add a "-a :8080" in there

Answer (score 0):

[The official Varnish Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/varnish) is quite basic at this point. As you concluded in your second post, you can use our the image as the basis, and then customize the behavior in your own `Dockerfile`.

However, for Varnish Software, it's an iterative process, so we'll gradually add features to the image. In the end, you'll be able to configure most parameters through environment variables in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

We're working on it, thanks for your patience.